# using imagemagic Convert batch operation takes too much time versus Gimp. How to execute per file in batch mode?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Using imagemagic Convert batch operation takes too much time versus Gimp. How to execute per file in batch mode?

The following command can be executed to bacth convert 200+ image files.
However, Convert / imagemagic creates tmp files for all images and then apply whatever process you gave to it eg. rotation.

```
 convert '*.jpg' -set filename:fn '%[basename]' -units PixelsPerInch  -rotate -90  -density 300 -quality 95  -resize 28% '%[filename:fn].jpg'
```

This means that it may consume a lot of memory / temporary disk size and it takes too much time. Now it is running more than 10+ minutes and not finished yet.

In comparison, GIMP -in batch mode- that makes operations per file (rotate, finish, next, rotate, finish, next etc.), it takes much less time (2-3 minutes).

I think GIMP uses imagemagick convert.

How can I run convert (in batch mode) in linux terminal and make operation PER FILE and not PER ALL FILES?

[image: many files from imagemagicjk convert]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By experimenting and looking for other examples,

i found that this imagemagick command operates per file and not in same time on all files:

```
 for pic in *.jpg; do convert -units PixelsPerInch  -rotate -90  -density 300 -quality 95  -resize 28% "$pic" "$pic";done
```

Note: if you dont want to replace original photo, the last "`$pic`" may be manipulated. eg. `"$pic" "${pic//}_copy.jpg"`

Comment: Why not just use mogrify? It processes one image at a time.

Comment: can you set "density" and "quallity" parameters in mogrify?

Comment: Yes, you can do all the same operations as above but for safety write your images to a newly created empty folder using the -path argument or duplicate your folder of input images so that if they get corrupted when writing back to the input folder, you have a backup. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to loop over your files, eg.:

```
parallel \
    convert {} -resize 28% -rotate -90 -quality 95 copy_{} \
    ::: *.jpg
```

(you don't need density, and its faster to shrink before rotate)

That'll run the convert commands in parallel. By default it'll use as many processes as you have cores. The `{}` is substituted for a filename when launching a command. You should get a nice speedup.

I tried a quick benchmark with a 10,000 x 10,000 pixel jpeg:

```
$ for i in {1..200}; do cp ~/wtc.jpg $i.jpg; done
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e parallel convert {} -resize 28% -rotate -90 -quality 95 copy_{} ::: *.jpg
962788:31.87
```

So 200 files were rotated and resized in 32s and conversion needed around 1gb of memory at peak.

Comment: But exactly the opposite i asked. To make operations per file and not per ALL files. It is not issue if resources, but issues of hard disk speed. Cause i running some other processes too - so many process in the same time. It has no the speed to execute all these (if process all files same time). 100mb/s is a serious limit. But i try now to migrate processes to other HDDs.

Comment: parallel will loop in groups by the number of cores you have, so if you have a four core machine, it'll run four converts at once. It's pretty great and well worth a try.

Comment: ... I added a benchmark.